# Google Translate javascript snippet not working

Tags: javascript, google-translate

I tried using the code snippet from w3school.com. It worked on w3school but doesnt work on my PC.

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
<script>

function googleTranslateElementInit() {
    new google.translate.TranslateElement({
        pageLanguage: 'en'
    }, 'google_translate_element');
}

</script>
<script src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

I got the following in the console.

```
translate.html:18 GET file://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The snippet over at [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_google_translate.asp) indeed has a bug.
It says to add the following line to include Google's API:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

Unfortunately the trailing **//** makes it point to a local file. So unless you've downloaded the library and bundled it with your html file this points to nowhere.
Instead link to the online library by adding **https:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

Comment: No problem Devetoka - glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

When you're running it on your machine, you're running it as a local file. As such, the source file, which is loading from `//translate.google` etc, is trying to find this file on google.

If you replace this with:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

you will find it is no longer trying to find a local file (i.e. on your machine), but instead will look for it on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

pure javascript, can be integrated from browser debug console, or in webview, or any site. In this example we just find element  and change his content to button (you can change any element you want)

```
importScriptURI("https://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js"); 
document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML='<div id="google_translate_element"></div>';
setTimeout(()=>{ new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en'},'google_translate_element');},1000);
```